# Pi Zero W 1.1 - What kind of component is this? What does it do?

Tags: hardware, pi-zero-w

Unfortunately a component (see image, component is encircled in red) is broken/missing on my **Pi Zero W 1.1**.

[image: Pi Zero W 1.1, broken/missing part is encircled]

So far **everything still seems to work**, but anyway:

- Do you know **what kind of component** this is (to be able to replace it)?
- Do you know **what it does** (to decide, if it needs replacing)?

**Update**: Here is a high-resolution image of the relevant part (a capacitor belonging to the antenna): [image: High-res. antenna photo]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a capacitor. It is required for the WiFi/Bluetooth antenna to work reliably.
It might still work without one of those but in general you should experience a degraded range and/or performance.

Comment: Thank you. You seem to be right about the WiFi/Bluetooth performance.. Do you happen to know the value of the capacitor (although replacing may be futile, if it has something to do with the antenna..)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any source that provides numbers. Only a statement that those are capacitors: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-wireless-antenna-design

Comment: maybe not helpful, but there are ways to attach an external antenna.

Comment: External antenna mod: https://www.briandorey.com/post/raspberry-pi-zero-w-external-antenna-mod